# Is it necessary to touch the mystery block?

Tags: pixel-hell

In Pixel Hell for iOS, you have to touch the pixel citizens before they fall into the fire. I am pretty bad at the game because I just started, but the first level has a mystery block that gives you a mystery power up. It could be good or bad, depending on your luck. Is there really a necessity to touch the mystery box? I don't want to take chances in figuring out because whenever it shows up, I'm only down to one life.